# Is it possible to run the Swift REPL within an SSH session?

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop

Has anyone tried running the Swift REPL within a local or remote SSH session?

`xcrun swift` runs great within a local Terminal session, but fails for me with

`error: failed to launch REPL process: process exited with status -1) (lost connection)`

in an SSH session (either remotely via iPad or when ssh'd into *localhost* directly on my desktop Mac).

Comment: what is the ssh command? do you try to run the REPL directly or within a login shell like bash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that OSX is trying to prompt you graphically for your password, but it can't do that over SSH. To get around this, you need to enable developer mode on the machine. You probably did it (unknowingly) by debugging a project in Xcode, which prompts you to enable developer mode.

[image: Developer mode prompt]

You can also run this from the command line (including over SSH):

```
sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity --enable
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, that's very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `swift` is in your shell path:

```
$ ssh -t localhost swift
Password:
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> 1
$R1: Int = 1
  2> var foo = 10
foo: Int = 10
  3> foo + 1
$R2: Int = 11
```

and remotely:

```
$ ssh -t gozoner@10.0.1.6 swift
Password:
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> 1
$R1: Int = 1
  2> 10
$R2: Int = 10
  3>
```

Comment: Thanks! The REPL is now working fine for me within an SSH session (both from Terminal to localhost, and from my iPad using Prompt). Perhaps I just needed to reboot my Mac after installing XCode 6 or switching the environment to use XCode 6.

Comment: Would appreciate an 'up vote' (realizing you changed your mind about 'an answer')